# tcpdump not writing output

Tags: tcpdump

I'm trying to capture packets at port 25. The following commands works fine (I can see output on the terminal whenever I send a test email):

```
tcpdump -ni any port 25
```

However the following command doesn't work

```
tcpdump -ni any port 25 2>/dev/null > dump.txt & echo $!;
```

By right that command should save output to dump.txt file (after killing the tcpdump process). I did this before. But in this system it creates dump.txt file, but it doesn't save output to that file.

I have read somewhere that maybe because the filesystem is full. How to know whether my filesystem is full? It seems I still have a lot of space.

```
root@pve:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G   17M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0        95G   12G   79G  13% /
tmpfs            16G   40M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/fuse        30M   28K   30M   1% /etc/pve
```

Comment: Reinstalling tcpdump solved the problem. I'm not sure what happened though :(

Comment: It is funny, and now it stops working again.